# How to get length of variable bash?

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

I use Cent OS 7, and have written a Bash script.

I tried to get the length of variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL_STRING="1";
VAR_LENGTH=${#URL_STRING}
echo $VAR_LENGTH;
```

But I get syntax error

Comment: Where is URL_STRING set? Also probz best not to use uppercase variable names as they are typically used for env variables.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Are you really in bash? What exact error do you get? It is a valid syntax you are using, so nothing should happen

Comment: This is valid posix shell syntax.  It works quite fine.  Here's a link to the Single Unix Specification stating what should be supported: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

`echo $URL_STRING| awk '{printf("%d",length($0))}' | read asd`

Comment: what is this supposed to be doing? what is the purpose of piping to read?